# requesting updates from LocationManager in my service. Is that good idea?

Tags: android, gps

Here is my idea.. Right now to preserve battery - I use some "fancy" logic where my service started by Alarm every 5 minutes, I request GPS location updates from `LocationManager` and wait up to 1 minute to get most accurate FIX.

This is all good, but after 5 minutes of inactivity GPS may take a while to "warm up" next time.

My idea was to monitor when device connected to charger and if connected - start another dummy service that will get LocationManager and request updates which will keep GPS ON for me while charger connected. This way when my "real" service kicks in every 5 minutes - GPS data will be there ready to go instantly.

Do I understand correctly that LocationManager will keep GPS ON as long as listeners count >0 ? Is my idea good or there is drawbacks to this approach?

Answer (score 0):

A drawback I can think of, is that usually there's no point in requesting updates from the GPS while the phone is connected to a charger, because in most cases a phone is charged inside a building, meaning no GPS signal.

Comment: Yes, in a car it makes sense. But in a building this will just significantly slow down the charging.

Comment: My app is for tracking fleet, devices usually on a road